# Доступ приложений к Интернету (Kerberos)

Tags: linux, proxy, kerberos

Есть корпоративная сеть, которая предоставляет доступ в интернет c аутентификацией на прокси-сервере по протоколу `Kerberos`.

Доступ браузера в интернет удалось получить, установив библиотеки `kerberos` и получая `ticket-cache` (`Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000`) командой `kinit`.

Как быть с приложениями, которые не умеют самостоятельно проходить аутентификацию по данному протоколу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `curl` должны быть установлены библиотеки `gssapi` и поддержка `GSS-API, Kerberos, SPNEGO`.

> ~$ curl -V
>
> ...
>
> Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile **GSS-API
>   Kerberos SPNEGO** NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets

Использование:

> curl https://example.com --proxy *proxy.domain.ru:port* --proxy-negotiate --proxy-user :

Двоеточие после `proxy-user` - это запись `username:password` с пустыми полями, т.к. протокол `Kerberos` требует аутентификации только при входе в домен (`kinit`).

Для работы других программ, можно использовать аутентифицирующий прокси-сервер `cntlm` с `kerberos`-патчем (например, https://github.com/metaphox/cntlm-gss).